# How to make my StreamWriter faster?

Tags: c#, filestream, streamreader, streamwriter

I have C# code like this :

```
string strFilePath = @
"E:\input.txt";
string strFilePath2 = @
"E:\output.txt";
const int BufferSize = 65536; // 64 Kilobytes
FileStream fs = new FileStream(strFilePath2, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs)) {
    for (int ww = 0; ww < File.ReadLines(strFilePath).Count(); ww++) {

        string tx2 = GetLine(strFilePath, ww).Replace("||", "| |");

        var first = String.Join("", tx2.TakeWhile(c => Char.IsDigit(c) || c == '|' || c == '-'));
        var third = String.Join("", tx2.Reverse().TakeWhile(c => Char.IsDigit(c) || c == '|' || c == '-').Reverse());
        var second = tx2.Replace(first, "").Replace(third, "");

        string awal = first.ToString();
        string dua = third.ToString();
        string gabung = (awal + dua).Replace("||", "|") + Environment.NewLine;

        string[] pdua = dua.Split('|');

        int totalkanan = int.Parse(pdua[1]) + int.Parse(pdua[2]) + int.Parse(pdua[3]) + int.Parse(pdua[4]) + int.Parse(pdua[5]) + int.Parse(pdua[6]) + int.Parse(pdua[7]) + int.Parse(pdua[8]) + int.Parse(pdua[9]) + int.Parse(pdua[10]) + int.Parse(pdua[11]) + int.Parse(pdua[12]) + int.Parse(pdua[13]) + int.Parse(pdua[14]) + int.Parse(pdua[15]) + int.Parse(pdua[16]) + int.Parse(pdua[17]) + int.Parse(pdua[18]) + int.Parse(pdua[19]);
        if (totalkanan > 0) {

            sw.Write(gabung);

        }
    }       
}
```

Get Line Method :

```
string GetLine(string fileName, int line)
{
 using (var sr = new StreamReader(fileName))
    {
      sr.ReadLine();
      for (int i = 1; i < line; i++)
      sr.ReadLine();
      return sr.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Input Example :

```
937|41|0|0|0|0|484|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|20||1|First lesson is when you'll be tested on your knowledge of the Elements of Darkness. Your task is to go get 20 Darkness elements from the Bale professors at the Zone of Darkness Elements.|2582|4342|1|0|0|0|0|470|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|
937|42|4335|1|0|0|470|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|2|Pass the test.|1||0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|
937|43|0|0|0|0|483|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|42||1|There are no more tests to take.|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|
937|44|7928|20|4348|1|481|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|42||1|Congratulations on your completion of all the lessons! Come back in a little while to receive your diploma.|2583|7928|-20|4348|-1|0|0|483|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|
937|45|7927|20|4347|1|479|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|42||1|Very nice~! Next, you'll be tested on the Elements of light.|2584|7927|-20|4347|-1|0|0|481|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|
937|46|7926|20|4346|1|477|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|42||1|Very nice~! Next, you'll be tested on the Elements of light.|2585|7926|-20|4346|-1|0|0|479|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|
```

Output :

```
937|41|0|0|0|0|484|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|20|2582|4342|1|0|0|0|0|470|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|
937|42|4335|1|0|0|470|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|2|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|
937|43|0|0|0|0|483|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|42|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|
937|44|7928|20|4348|1|481|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|42|2583|7928|-20|4348|-1|0|0|483|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|
937|45|7927|20|4347|1|479|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|42|2584|7927|-20|4347|-1|0|0|481|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|
937|46|7926|20|4346|1|477|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|42|2585|7926|-20|4346|-1|0|0|479|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|
```

This program is working , but the problem is when input file has 17k ++ line, the writing progress is very slow , but when input file just 4k+ it just about 10 second , the logic is why 4k take 10 sec , while 17k more than 5 minutes ? 
any suggestion to solving this ? Thank you in advance !

Comment: Complexity is not linear :) - You should give us a bit of input to test it

Comment: Show the `GetLine` method

Comment: @Thomas hahaha yeah , i'm new to c# , but i just have an idea how about separate process every write 4k lines ? :D

Comment: `for (int ww = 0; ww < File.ReadLines(strFilePath).Count(); ww++) {` why not store the `ReadLines().Count` somewhere instead of evaluating it on every call, this is probably slowing you down. Each time you loop, the entire file is read back in again, and then the lines are counted. This is expensive!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to [CodeReview.se]

Comment: 'ww < File.ReadLines(strFilePath).Count()' this will read the file after every iteration. The size of the file will determine whether it is cached or not, which in turn will have a big effect on the time.

Comment: Have you considered using [File.ReadAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx) and [File.WriteAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92e05ft3(v=vs.110).aspx) ?

Comment: And could you provide desired output to compare?

Comment: @RonBeyer okay i will try that and Andy Okay as RonBeyer and your suggestion i will try it now

Comment: And your `GetLine` function is opening the file again, reading *all the lines* up to the one you want and then returning. So for the first line, you read the first line. For the second line, you *read the first line again* and then read the second line. For the third line, you *read the first two lines again* and then read the third line. That's horribly inefficient.

Comment: @Thomas Output added..

Comment: so, basically, you want to remove all text in between the pipes, right?

Comment: @Thomas yeah , you're right ,i want to remove all text between pipes with dynamical text on it maybe empty , maybe it filled

Comment: @user3409182 Try this one-liner: `File.WriteAllLines(@"E:\output.txt", File.ReadLines(@"E:\input.txt").AsParallel().Select(line => String.Join(String.Empty, line.Split(new[] { "|" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Where(segment => segment.All(c => Char.IsDigit(c) || c == '-')).Select(segment => String.Format("{0}|", segment)))));`

Comment: I have this one : `File.WriteAllLines("output.txt", File.ReadAllLines("input.txt").ToList().Select(s => Regex.Replace(s, "[A-Z]+[^\\|]*", "")).ToList());
`

Comment: @Thomas Oh, much shorter. Me like that! All hail regular expressions :P

Comment: Looks like there is some data loss on the original implementation as well, anywhere there is a double pipe (II) the following value does not look like it gets copied to the output...

Comment: @MatiasCicero too bad the question is closed :(

Comment: Yeah , i just tried this Thomas solution leave ||1|| on the middle of two section , ||1|| <- is the text section too :) so i need to remove it too

Comment: @MatiasCicero The line in your code, i just place it on foreach give me an error (The line giving different meaning) btw i use `foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(strFilePath))`

Comment: @user3409182 Don't place it on any foreach. The whole line replaces all your code. The line by itself should do all the work.

Comment: @Thomas , Matias Cicero, Ron Beyer, Andy, and Matt Burland , Thank you my problem solved without changing anything about string processing , my problem solved using below accepted answer :) Thank you very much too , to teach me about using different method for string processing !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `GetLine()` method has to read the whole file (upto the line in question), each time to get 1 line.

Because of this, you will see exponentially poor performance.

Why not just read each line as you go?

```
string strFilePath = @"E:\input.txt";
string strFilePath2 = @"E:\output.txt";
const int BufferSize = 65536; // 64 Kilobytes

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
{
    foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(strFilePath))
    {
        string tx2 = line.Replace("||", "| |");
        var first = String.Join("", tx2.TakeWhile(c => Char.IsDigit(c) || c == '|' || c == '-'));
        var third = String.Join("", tx2.Reverse().TakeWhile(c => Char.IsDigit(c) || c == '|' || c == '-').Reverse());
        var second = tx2.Replace(first, "").Replace(third, "");

        string awal = first.ToString();
        string dua = third.ToString();
        string gabung = (awal + dua).Replace("||", "|") + Environment.NewLine;

        string[] pdua = dua.Split('|');

        int totalkanan = int.Parse(pdua[1]) + int.Parse(pdua[2]) + int.Parse(pdua[3]) + int.Parse(pdua[4]) + int.Parse(pdua[5]) + int.Parse(pdua[6]) + int.Parse(pdua[7]) + int.Parse(pdua[8]) + int.Parse(pdua[9]) + int.Parse(pdua[10]) + int.Parse(pdua[11]) + int.Parse(pdua[12]) + int.Parse(pdua[13]) + int.Parse(pdua[14]) + int.Parse(pdua[15]) + int.Parse(pdua[16]) + int.Parse(pdua[17]) + int.Parse(pdua[18]) + int.Parse(pdua[19]);
        if (totalkanan > 0)
        {
            sw.Write(gabung);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and give me an error , on int totalkanan , it said out of bound , if i use for like my code , it never out of bound , why?

Comment: Nvm , your answer is working to me! , now it just take about 20 ms :)

Answer (score 3):

You are doing a **lot** of string manipulation in inefficient ways which will result in a lot of allocations and as a result a lot of garbage collection both of which will slow you down.

It also looks like you are reading the file once to get the number of lines, then per line re-reading that file each time to get the next line from the file!

The [File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file(v=vs.110).aspx) class has other methods which are more efficient, do something like this instead:

```
int lineNumber = 0;
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(path))
{
    lineNumber++;

    // process line
}
```

*Also do you know that arrays start at index 0, `pdua[1]` is the second item in the array...*

Comment: yeah i know if array start at index 0 , i write it pdua[1] because pdua[0] is empty when i try to Console.Write it :) how horrible my code many string manipulation hahaha , i need to get the output but never think about performance when first time write this code